# Kotlin room query not returning in time

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Here is where i get the problem

```
viewModelScope.launch {
            workout?.let { workout ->
                // Workout is not null
                steps = stepDao.getWorkoutSteps(workout.workoutId)
                Log.e(tag, "steps old : ${workout.workoutId}")
            } ?: run {
                // Workout is null, let's create it
                newWorkoutAndStepsId = workoutDao.insert(Workout("")).toInt()
                Log.e(tag, "steps new : $newWorkoutAndStepsId")

                var step1id = stepDao.insert(Step("Warm Up Jumping Jacks", 1, false, "minute", newWorkoutAndStepsId)).toInt()
                Log.e(tag, "steps new : new step id $step1id")
                stepDao.insert(Step("Rest", 15, true, "second", newWorkoutAndStepsId))

                steps = stepDao.getWorkoutSteps(newWorkoutAndStepsId)


                //steps = stepDao.getWorkoutSteps(25)
            }
        }
```

the steps don't get returned in the case of the new workout, if i hard code the id then they do, the Logs both return ids as expected, but still the steps aren't returned

thanks!

Comment: What do you mean the "steps aren't returned"? A `launch` coroutine doesn't return anything besides a Job. If you launch the coroutine and immediately try to use `steps` afterwards, `steps` will not have been set yet because the coroutine is still running. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68370029/506796).

Comment: how do i get the steps then?

Comment: Get rid of the property. Use a local variable for it inside the coroutine. Use it inside the coroutine.

Comment: can that be accessed from the viewmodel?

Comment: yes sorry i wrote that wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coroutines are asynchronous. You can't expect the results of what the coroutine does to be immediately available after launching it. [See here for an explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68370029/506796)

From the comments, you say you want the steps to use in the Fragment. There are a few ways to do this.

I don't know the type of steps so I'll just use WorkoutSteps as the type in my examples. Also, I think it is very error-prone and has poor readability to chain scope functions, so I'll do it without them.

1. Make this a suspend function instead of launching a coroutine. In the Fragment, call the suspend function from within a coroutine to get the value and use it inside the coroutine.

```
suspend fun getSteps(): WorkoutSteps = when (val workout = workout) {
  null -> { // Workout is null, let's create it
    newWorkoutAndStepsId = workoutDao.insert(Workout("")).toInt()
    Log.e(tag, "steps new : $newWorkoutAndStepsId")

    val step1id = stepDao.insert(Step("Warm Up Jumping Jacks", 1, false, "minute", newWorkoutAndStepsId)).toInt()
    Log.e(tag, "steps new : new step id $step1id")
    stepDao.insert(Step("Rest", 15, true, "second", newWorkoutAndStepsId))
    stepDao.getWorkoutSteps(newWorkoutAndStepsId)
  }
  else -> stepDao.getWorkoutSteps(workout.workoutId).also {
     Log.e(tag, "steps old : $it")
  }
}
```

2. Expose a LiveData for the Fragment to persistently observe for results. The LiveData will initially have no value. After `refreshSteps()` is called, the results will come in later via the LiveData. So the Fragment should observe the LiveData and call `refreshSteps()` separately.

```
private val _steps = MutableLiveData<WorkoutSteps>()
val steps: LiveData<WorkoutSteps> get() = _steps

fun refreshSteps() = viewModelScope.launch {
  _steps.value = when(val workout = workout) {
    null -> { // Workout is null, let's create it
      newWorkoutAndStepsId = workoutDao.insert(Workout("")).toInt()
      Log.e(tag, "steps new : $newWorkoutAndStepsId")

      val step1id = stepDao.insert(Step("Warm Up Jumping Jacks", 1, false, "minute", newWorkoutAndStepsId)).toInt()
      Log.e(tag, "steps new : new step id $step1id")
      stepDao.insert(Step("Rest", 15, true, "second", newWorkoutAndStepsId))
      stepDao.getWorkoutSteps(newWorkoutAndStepsId)
    }
    else -> stepDao.getWorkoutSteps(workout.workoutId).also {
      Log.e(tag, "steps old : $it")
    }
  }
}
```

3. You can do the same as 2 using StateFlow instead of LiveData.
4. Instead of a suspend function, you could expose a regular function with callback parameter. But that's an overcomplicated solution in a project that is already using coroutines.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, i made all the changes you said, i now get a "Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time." error,

Comment: Whatever function is giving you that error should be marked as a `suspend` function in the DAO.

Answer (score 0):

okay so for anyone else reading this, i made the changes @Tenfour04 suggested, and also added `Dispatchers.IO` as an argument to the `viewModelScope.launch` methods, and also had to change `_steps.value =` ... to `_step.postValue(...)`
thanks for everyone who answered

Comment: You must be calling blocking DAO functions if that's the case. Mark your DAO functions as `suspend` so you don't have to worry about specifying IO dispatcher and posting values.